# How do i gray out a radio button after N minutes?

Tags: jquery, html

How do i gray out the radio button after N minutes if the user does not enter any input?

Is there a jQuery method or plugin that does this?

Thanks!

Comment: Clearly this question is unclear.

Comment: Break this down into smaller tasks. I will give you a couply clues: disabled attribute, css opacity, javascript setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you asked this, if i am not mistaken:

```
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"><span class="radioButtonText">Male</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"><span class="radioButtonText">Female</span><br>
  <br />
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        //Timer Functionality
        var myVar = setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 4000);
        function myTimer() {
           $("input[name = gender]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
           $(".radioButtonText").css('color', 'grey');
        }
        //If user puts an input, stop Timer Functionality
     $("input[name=gender]").click(function () {
        clearTimeout(myVar);
     });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this...

```
setTimeout(function(){
     document.getElementById("your_radio_button_id").disabled = true;
},2000)//Instead of 2000 you can use whatever you want
```

Hope it will work

Comment: Just the clarify to the OP: 2000 is in milliseconds. For N minutes, use N*60000 as the value.

Comment: yes 2000 is milliseconds.. right bro

Comment: What about the "if the user doesn't enter any input" part?